# How to find which command is executed by a symlink?

Tags: symlink

Somewhere in my system (the problem is I don't know where) I have a symlink to which is given priority by `bash` but the link is broken and therefore it doesn't work.

More specifically:

- current directory: `mysymlink`
- somewhere in path (installed by a package): `mysymlink`

**when running `mysymlink` from current directory, the (broken) symlink `mysymlink` somewhere in the file system is called.**

I am trying to find that symlink, delete it so I can use the one in the current directory.

**How do I find it?**

**(EDIT) CONCRETE EXAMPLE**:

command -v testcafe

> /usr/local/bin/testcafe

ls -l /usr/local/bin/testcafe

> ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/testcafe: No such file or directory

(Note: **I removed myself the target path** by mistake)

**How to remove this symlink (somewhere in the system)?**

Comment: Your question is unclear, and you should tell what you really want to do ... and what commands you have tried... Is your thing a `testcafe`  or a `mysymlink`? And what exactly is your `$PATH` ?

Comment: I explained it to my best as I am not very very experienced with synlinks. the answer I accepted explains it better. I pasted most of the updated information in my question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try (assuming that `ls` is *not* aliased; if it is replace it by `/bin/ls`)

```
ls -l $(which mysymlink)
```

since `which mysymlink` gives the full path of the command `mysymlink` (i.e. expands using [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)))

You need to try that command *outside* of the directory containing `mysymlink`.

BTW, it looks like `.` is in your `$PATH`. You can check with `echo $PATH`. And having the current directory in your `$PATH` can be a security risk.

> ls: cannot access `/usr/local/bin/testcafe`: No such file or directory

Then check with `ls -dl /usr/ /usr/local/ /usr/local/bin/` which of these directories don't exist (perhaps you forgot to *mount* some file system, or you removed by mistake, as root, some of these directories).

And of course do also a `ls -l /usr/local/bin/testcafe`

(you should try with `/bin/ls` instead of `ls` because I guess that your `ls` is aliased or redefined)

> How to remove this symlink (somewhere in the system)?

You need first to find it. Use [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) appropriately (probably with `-lname`)

Comment: I removed myself the broken target path. I'm trying to understand where symlink originally pointing to it is located

Comment: @dragonmnl: That should go into your question, which you should edit.

Comment: sure, just did it

Answer (score 4):

`command -v UTILITY` will show you what the shell would try to execute if you gave the command `UTILITY`.

Since it reports

```
/usr/local/bin/testcafe
```

but then

```
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/testcafe: No such file or directory
```

when you try to `ls -l` it, it leads me to believe that the reported location of the `testcafe` utility has been cached by the shell, and since removed.

To refresh the shell's cache, use `hash -r` (this command outputs nothing).  This will flush the cache and the shell will then do a full path lookup the next time you run `testcafe`.

Comment: that just shows what the symlink runs, not *where* the symlink is (i.e. it shows the broken link, but not where the symlink is "taken")

Comment: @dragonmnl It will show you the location of the symbolic link. Using `ls -l` on the link will tell you where it points to. If that too is a symbolic link, repeat until you find the broken ink.

Comment: please see the concrete example in my question (just added)

Comment: @dragonmnl It is hashed. Use `hash -r` to rehash.

Comment: complete command? hash -r does nothing

Comment: @dragonmnl ... and then try the command again.

Answer (score 2):

To find broken symlinks in all directories in your `PATH`, with `bash`:

```
IFS=: read -ra dirs <<<"$PATH"
find -L "${dirs[@]}" -type l -maxdepth 1
```

Add `-delete` to `find` to delete them.